# Javascript_api_promise problem / need faster solution

Tags: javascript, api, promise

agsi web gives api to single gas chamber operator, there are few operators in some countries. I have to get sum of all operators. For Example in Germany there are 25 - SSO (storage system operators). I have an api for each of them.

I managed to get array of sum what I wanted, but it takes 20 seconds for Germany (largest)

What is the best way to get and use this data in chart, I am storing data locally. (maybe save as CSV once a day and with D3 or input data as variables in js file with python?
I am using it for learning purposes and now I am not enough skilled to use server side.

```js
let apiKey = "709a7d013e4fda8f3e21166c33a1a691";
let urls = [
'https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/https://agsi.gie.eu/api/data/21X000000001160J/DE',
'https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/https://agsi.gie.eu/api/data/37X0000000000151/DE',
'https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/https://agsi.gie.eu/api/data/37X0000000000224/DE',
'https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/https://agsi.gie.eu/api/data/21X000000001125L/DE',
'https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/https://agsi.gie.eu/api/data/21X0000000010849/DE',
'https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/https://agsi.gie.eu/api/data/21X000000001368W/DE',
'https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/https://agsi.gie.eu/api/data/21X0000000011756/DE',
'https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/https://agsi.gie.eu/api/data/21X000000001090E/DE',
'https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/https://agsi.gie.eu/api/data/21X0000000013805/DE',
'https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/https://agsi.gie.eu/api/data/21X000000001262B/DE',
'https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/https://agsi.gie.eu/api/data/21X000000001140P/DE',
'https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/https://agsi.gie.eu/api/data/37X000000000042Z/DE',
'https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/https://agsi.gie.eu/api/data/21X0000000011748/DE',
'https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/https://agsi.gie.eu/api/data/11XNERGIE------1/DE',
'https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/https://agsi.gie.eu/api/data/37X0000000000119/DE',
'https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/https://agsi.gie.eu/api/data/25X-OMVGASSTORA5/DE',
'https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/https://agsi.gie.eu/api/data/11XSWHANNOVERAG3/DE',
'https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/https://agsi.gie.eu/api/data/21X000000001072G/DE',
'https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/https://agsi.gie.eu/api/data/11XSWB-BREMEN--I/DE',
'https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/https://agsi.gie.eu/api/data/37X000000000051Y/DE',
'https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/https://agsi.gie.eu/api/data/21X000000001307F/DE',
'https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/https://agsi.gie.eu/api/data/21X000000001310Q/DE',
'https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/https://agsi.gie.eu/api/data/21X000000001127H/DE',
'https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/https://agsi.gie.eu/api/data/21X000000001138C/DE',
];

let requests = urls.map((url) =>
  fetch(url, {
    method: "GET",
    headers: {
      "x-key": apiKey
    }
  }).then((res) => res.json())
);

Promise.all(requests).then((response) => arr_api_agsi(response));

function arr_api_agsi(response) {
  var arr_api=[];
  var l=[];
  var i;
  var j;
  var jj;
  var gas_date;
 var response_length=response.length
  for (i = 0; i < response_length; i++) {
         arr_api.push(response[i]);
         l.push(response[i].length);
  }
  var gas_vol=0;
  var arr_max_index=0;
  l.map((u)=>u.length>l[arr_max_index].length ? arr_max_index=l.indexOf(u.length):x=1);

  var gas_storage=[];
  var gas_storage_temp=[];
  var len_single_arr;
 var len_max_arr=arr_api[arr_max_index].length
  for(i=0;i<len_max_arr;i++){  //for all dates in max length array
   len_max_arr_j=arr_api.length
    for(j=0;j<len_max_arr_j;j++){ //for all arrays
     len_single_arr=arr_api[j].length
      for(jj=0;jj< len_single_arr;jj++){ //for all dates in single array
        if (arr_api[arr_max_index][i]["gasDayStartedOn"]==arr_api[j][jj]["gasDayStartedOn"] &&  isNaN(parseFloat(arr_api[j][jj]["gasInStorage"]))==false) {
          gas_vol+=parseFloat(arr_api[j][jj]["gasInStorage"]);
          gas_date=arr_api[j][jj]["gasDayStartedOn"];
        }
      }
    }
    gas_storage_temp.push([gas_date,gas_vol]);
    gas_storage=gas_storage.concat(gas_storage_temp);
    gas_storage_temp=[];
    gas_vol=0;
  }
console.log(gas_storage)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use **transducers** to solve your performance problem here.

First, install [deno](https://github.com/denoland/deno_install).

Here is a script that you can run manually, then schedule as a cron job if you want automation.

You can run it like so: `deno run --allow-net gas.js`

`gas.js`

```js
import {
  pipe, fork, tap, map, filter, reduce, transform, get, not,
} from 'https://deno.land/x/rubico/rubico.js'

const apiKey = "709a7d013e4fda8f3e21166c33a1a691"

const urls = [
  'https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/https://agsi.gie.eu/api/data/21X000000001160J/DE',
  'https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/https://agsi.gie.eu/api/data/37X0000000000151/DE',
  'https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/https://agsi.gie.eu/api/data/37X0000000000224/DE',
  'https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/https://agsi.gie.eu/api/data/21X000000001125L/DE',
  'https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/https://agsi.gie.eu/api/data/21X0000000010849/DE',
  'https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/https://agsi.gie.eu/api/data/21X000000001368W/DE',
  'https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/https://agsi.gie.eu/api/data/21X0000000011756/DE',
  'https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/https://agsi.gie.eu/api/data/21X000000001090E/DE',
  'https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/https://agsi.gie.eu/api/data/21X0000000013805/DE',
  'https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/https://agsi.gie.eu/api/data/21X000000001262B/DE',
  'https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/https://agsi.gie.eu/api/data/21X000000001140P/DE',
  'https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/https://agsi.gie.eu/api/data/37X000000000042Z/DE',
  'https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/https://agsi.gie.eu/api/data/21X0000000011748/DE',
  'https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/https://agsi.gie.eu/api/data/11XNERGIE------1/DE',
  'https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/https://agsi.gie.eu/api/data/37X0000000000119/DE',
  'https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/https://agsi.gie.eu/api/data/25X-OMVGASSTORA5/DE',
  'https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/https://agsi.gie.eu/api/data/11XSWHANNOVERAG3/DE',
  'https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/https://agsi.gie.eu/api/data/21X000000001072G/DE',
  'https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/https://agsi.gie.eu/api/data/11XSWB-BREMEN--I/DE',
  'https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/https://agsi.gie.eu/api/data/37X000000000051Y/DE',
  'https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/https://agsi.gie.eu/api/data/21X000000001307F/DE',
  'https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/https://agsi.gie.eu/api/data/21X000000001310Q/DE',
  'https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/https://agsi.gie.eu/api/data/21X000000001127H/DE',
  'https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/https://agsi.gie.eu/api/data/21X000000001138C/DE',
]

const getData = url => fetch(url, {
  method: 'GET',
  headers: {
    'x-key': apiKey,
    'Origin': null,
  },
}).then(res => res.json())

const incrementMap = (y, xi) => {
  const [gasDate, gasVol] = xi
  if (y.has(gasDate)) {
    y.set(gasDate, y.get(gasDate) + gasVol)
  } else {
    y.set(gasDate, gasVol)
  }
  return y
}

// url => [gas_record]
const toGasDateVolRecordsMap = url => pipe([
  getData,
  reduce(pipe([
    map(fork([
      get('gasDayStartedOn'),
      pipe([get('gasInStorage'), parseFloat]),
    ])),
    filter(pipe([get(1), not(isNaN)])),
  ])(incrementMap), new Map()),
  tap(() => console.log('done with', url)),
])(url)

// mapA, mapB -> mapC
const combineMaps = (y, xi) => {
  let newMap = y
  for (const record of xi) {
    newMap = incrementMap(newMap, record)
  }
  return y
}

console.log('beginning requests')
const now = Date.now()
const finalMap = await pipe([
  map(toGasDateVolRecordsMap),
  reduce(combineMaps, new Map()),
])(urls)

console.log(finalMap, 'in', Date.now() - now, 'ms')
```

Here were my results in my last run

```
Map {
  "2020-05-21" => 185.76999999999998,
  "2020-05-20" => 185.1071,
  "2020-05-19" => 184.6843,
  "2020-05-18" => 184.32969999999997,
  "2020-05-17" => 183.7246,
  "2020-05-16" => 182.92209999999997,
  "2020-05-15" => 182.33570000000003,
  "2020-05-14" => 182.1236,
  "2020-05-13" => 182.0282,
  "2020-05-12" => 181.98539999999997,
  "2020-05-11" => 182.32399999999998,
  "2020-05-10" => 181.7332,
  "2020-05-09" => 180.5206,
  "2020-05-08" => 179.3828,
  "2020-05-07" => 178.50409999999997,
  "2020-05-06" => 178.0811,
  "2020-05-05" => 177.8532,
  "2020-05-04" => 177.62040000000002,
  "2020-05-03" => 177.2416,
  "2020-05-02" => 176.63550000000004,
  "2020-05-01" => 175.9856,
  "2020-04-30" => 175.1376,
  "2020-04-29" => 174.47029999999998,
  "2020-04-28" => 173.93019999999999,
  "2020-04-27" => 173.61330000000004,
  "2020-04-26" => 173.28529999999998,
  "2020-04-25" => 172.62169999999998,
  "2020-04-24" => 171.8595,
  "2020-04-23" => 171.2766,
  "2020-04-22" => 170.8136,
  "2020-04-21" => 170.1925,
  "2020-04-20" => 169.55120000000002,
  "2020-04-19" => 169.0327,
  "2020-04-18" => 168.12290000000002,
  "2020-04-17" => 167.17200000000003,
  "2020-04-16" => 166.79960000000003,
  "2020-04-15" => 166.4389,
  "2020-04-14" => 166.3951,
  "2020-04-13" => 166.4094,
  "2020-04-12" => 165.82659999999998,
  "2020-04-11" => 164.98540000000003,
  "2020-04-10" => 164.2925,
  "2020-04-09" => 163.71460000000002,
  "2020-04-08" => 163.22520000000003,
  "2020-04-07" => 162.8278,
  "2020-04-06" => 162.46410000000003,
  "2020-04-05" => 162.05689999999998,
  "2020-04-04" => 161.66649999999998,
  "2020-04-03" => 161.48640000000003,
  "2020-04-02" => 161.7566,
  "2020-04-01" => 162.1767,
  "2020-03-31" => 160.53390000000005,
  "2020-03-30" => 162.0816,
  "2020-03-29" => 163.01540000000003,
  "2020-03-28" => 163.20020000000002,
  "2020-03-27" => 163.1253,
  "2020-03-26" => 163.52140000000003,
  "2020-03-25" => 164.3272,
  "2020-03-24" => 165.20749999999998,
  "2020-03-23" => 165.9939,
  "2020-03-22" => 166.9542,
  "2020-03-21" => 167.37539999999998,
  "2020-03-20" => 167.7758,
  "2020-03-19" => 168.15980000000002,
  "2020-03-18" => 168.52270000000001,
  "2020-03-17" => 168.68449999999999,
  "2020-03-16" => 168.9426,
  "2020-03-15" => 169.2491,
  "2020-03-14" => 169.4138,
  "2020-03-13" => 169.8962,
  "2020-03-12" => 170.3027,
  "2020-03-11" => 170.4511,
  "2020-03-10" => 170.6003,
  "2020-03-09" => 170.9641,
  "2020-03-08" => 171.48220000000003,
  "2020-03-07" => 171.61350000000002,
  "2020-03-06" => 172.0182,
  "2020-03-05" => 172.5045,
  "2020-03-04" => 173.2632,
  "2020-03-03" => 173.9052,
  "2020-03-02" => 174.4052,
  "2020-03-01" => 175.70919999999998,
  "2020-02-29" => 176.10870000000003,
  "2020-02-28" => 176.14049999999997,
  "2020-02-27" => 177.47449999999998,
  "2020-02-26" => 178.7926,
  "2020-02-25" => 179.75709999999998,
  "2020-02-24" => 180.1693,
  "2020-02-23" => 180.71120000000002,
  "2020-02-22" => 180.8336,
  "2020-02-21" => 181.0428,
  "2020-02-20" => 181.5118,
  "2020-02-19" => 182.02380000000002,
  "2020-02-18" => 182.5467,
  "2020-02-17" => 183.13459999999998,
  "2020-02-16" => 183.5387,
  "2020-02-15" => 183.539,
  "2020-02-14" => 183.67700000000005,
  "2020-02-13" => 184.24939999999998,
  "2020-02-12" => 185.1237,
  ... 3329 more items
} in 7902 ms
```

If you don't like the `Map` at the end, you can do `Array.from(finalMap)` to get an `Array`.